# Function returns zero features GEE when filter image collection by date

Tags: google-earth-engine, javascript, filter, date

I am trying to create a function that filters a collection by a date range.
In my code, the user can select two dates in which they want to create an anlysis.
The way the code is build, the users fill in the dates of analysis by:

```
//Selection of analysis dates
var header3 = ui.Label('3. Select analysis dates', {'fontWeight': 'bold','font-size': '14px'});
var dateSelect1 = ui.Textbox({placeholder:'yy-DDD', value: '2021-001'}); //my data has the format of julian dates
var dateSelect2 = ui.Textbox({placeholder:'yy-DDD', value: '2021-165'});

var outputs = {}
outputs.dateSelect1 = dateSelect1;
outputs.dateSelect2 = dateSelect2;

return(outputs);
}

var fecha1 = ee.Date(interfazUser.dateSelect1.getValue()); 
var fecha2 = ee.Date(interfazUser.dateSelect2.getValue());
var dateSelect1 = interfazUser.dateSelect1.getValue();
var dateSelect2 = interfazUser.dateSelect2.getValue();


var date1 = ee.Number(fecha1.getRelative('day','year'));
var date2 = ee.Number(fecha2.getRelative('day','year'));
var dateYear1 = dateSelect1.slice(0,4);
var dateYear2 = dateSelect2.slice(0,4);

var timeNow = ee.Date(Date.now());
var yearNow = timeNow.get('year');
var yearPre = timeNow.advance(-1,'year').get('year');
var yearNowS = ee.String(yearNow).getInfo();
var yearPreS = ee.String(yearPre).getInfo();
var yearNowShort = ee.String(yearNow).slice(2,4).getInfo();
var yearPreShort = ee.String(yearPre).slice(2,4).getInfo();

var bandasPre = ['Date' + yearPreShort,'Alert'+ yearPreShort];
var bandasAct = ['Date'+ yearNowShort,'Alert'+ yearNowShort];

var bandasRADD;
var raddfilter;
var mosaicoLandsatEnero;//not needed
var raddLast;
var lastAlerts,lastAlerts2,lastAlerts3,lastAlerts4,lastAlerts5;
var raddRegion = raddConfirmedCollection.filterBounds(region); 
print(raddRegion, 'raddregion') //is correct
```

However, when I try to perform the analysis, it does not work as the function below returns an empty variable that i need after (raddfilter).

```
//Selection of alerts case 1 (yearpre-yearpre)
if(dateYear1 === yearPreS && dateYear2 === yearPreS ){
  //raddfilter = raddRegion.filterDate(yearNowS +'0101',yearNowS +'0102');
  raddfilter = raddRegion.filterDate(fecha1,fecha2); //empty - problem is there
  bandasRADD = bandasPre;
  mosaicoLandsatEnero = funciones.landsatMosaic(ee.Date(yearPreS+'-01-01'),region).select(['red','nir','swir1','obsDate']);//not needed, remove 
  raddLast = raddfilter.sort('system:time_start',false).first();
  lastAlerts = raddLast.select(bandasRADD[1]).clip(region);
  lastAlerts2 = lastAlerts.selfMask();
  lastAlerts3 = lastAlerts2.where(raddLast.select(bandasRADD[0]).lt(date1),0);
  lastAlerts4 = lastAlerts3.where(raddLast.select(bandasRADD[0]).gt(date2),0);
  lastAlerts5 = lastAlerts4.selfMask();
}
```

Raddregion is image collection with two bands, 0 - Alert, 1- Date.

The link to the code can be found here: https://code.earthengine.google.com/d46bbee22e73b7f482ae9701935e9431?accept_repo=users%2FPrioGLADpy%2Fui_ES

However, it is very long (more than 1200 lines) and because its creating an userinterface, it is nearly impossible for me to simplify it. The problem occurs in line 457.

Can someone help me please?

Comment: I don't know if I understand your question. Do you want to filter alerts from a user-supplied time range?

Comment: yes, the user can fill in two dates in which i want to analyze the occurence of alerts

Comment: You have a misplaced single quote `'` at the end of line 4 in your posted code which is causing the bulk of it to appear as a string.

Comment: Oh yes sorry! i fixed it